# Problems with footparagraph

Tags: footnotes

LaTeX Error: \Afootparagraph undefined.

What's wrong? This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfsync}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}
\sidenotemargin{left}
\ledlsnotesep 50pt

\renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\raggedleft\scriptsize}
\renewcommand{\ledrsnotefontsetup}{\raggedright\scriptsize}


%\let\Afootnoterule=\relax
\let\Bfootnoterule=\relax
\let\Cfootnoterule=\relax
```

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \Afootparagraph
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: That is the error. Can you show the code that causes the error? Preferably in the form of a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/), i.e. the smallest complete document demonstrating the problem.